# quickbooks magento 2.3 QBWC1012

Tags: magento, quickbooks, magento-2.3

I'm migrating a store from magento 1 to magento 2 and they have it integrated with Quickbooks Desktop on a MQC remote desktop.

I'm using consolibyte on both m1 and m2. And it was working on m2 as well. Then I had to put aside this task and updated magento to 2.3.0.

Now when I try to update my magneto 2 application in the web connector on the remote desktop it gives me the following error:

```
"Version:
Not provided by service

Message:
Authentication failed

Description:
QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
The request failed with an empty response. See QWCLog for more details. Remember to turn logging on."
```

The log looks like this:

```
"20190213.06:57:36 UTC  : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'Sansha 2 France 1.0' has STARTED
20190213.06:57:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20190213.06:57:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20190213.06:57:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20190213.06:57:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20190213.06:57:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: Sansha 2 France 1.0
20190213.06:57:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): Sansha 2 France 1.0
20190213.06:57:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: https://eurostore.magento2.sansha.com/quickbooks/api
20190213.06:57:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20190213.06:57:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: <The request failed with an empty response.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.
20190213.06:57:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20190213.06:57:36 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.2.0.71">
20190213.06:57:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: <The request failed with an empty response.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-clientVersion.
20190213.06:57:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20190213.06:57:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'Sansha 2 France 1.0', username = 'sansha'
20190213.06:57:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="sansha"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20190213.06:57:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
The request failed with an empty response.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services
20190213.06:57:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20190213.06:57:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20190213.06:57:37 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
"
```

I tried to find a solution but still no luck.

The SOAP server seems like working:

```
"QuickBooks PHP DevKit Server v3.0 at /quickbooks/api/
   (c) "Keith Palmer" <keith@consolibyte.com> 
   Visit us at: http://www.ConsoliBYTE.com/ 

Use the QuickBooks Web Connector to access this SOAP server.

QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server::handle() parameters: 
 - $return = 1
 - $debug  = 1

Misc. information: 
 - Logging: 1
 - Timezone: Europe/Paris (Auto-set: )
 - Current Date/Time: 2019-02-14 08:09:29
 - Error Reporting: 32767

SOAP adapter: 
 - QuickBooks_Adapter_Server_Builtin

Registered handler functions: 
Array
(
    [0] => __construct
    [1] => authenticate
    [2] => sendRequestXML
    [3] => receiveResponseXML
    [4] => connectionError
    [5] => getLastError
    [6] => closeConnection
    [7] => serverVersion
    [8] => clientVersion
)

Detected input: 


Timestamp: 
 - 2019-02-14 08:09:29 -- process 0.27981"
```

And this is how it is initiated:

```
if(!\QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn)) {
    \QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);
    \QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $qb_username, $qb_password);
}

$server = new \QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $this->_map, $this->_errmap, $this->_hooks);
$response = $server->handle(true, true);
```

Did anyone faced this problem? Do someone know how can it be solved.

Regards

Comment: Anything in your PHP error log?

Comment: Hi Keith, I have nothing related to this in the error log. We have a magento 1 installation that works. This is a magneto 2 which we want to migrate to. It was working, had to put is aside, updated to  2.3.0 and it gives the errors above. P.S.: "Sorry for the late reply"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue finally.

The point is that updating to magento 2.3 breaks HTTP POST request, or at least the way they were working before the update, see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253414/magento-2-3-upgrade-breaks-http-post-requests-to-custom-module-endpoint.

I used https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/dev/dev_qbwc_tester.php to test the request and the form key was not valid. To fix this your controller has to implement CsrfAwareActionInterface.

And to prevent magento from trying to set cookies and rewrite headers after your QBWC server is initialized you will have to block your code just after the SOAP server is initialized. I put a die() after, not sure is the best solution, but authentication work (this was my primary issue).

The final code in the controller looks like this:

```
<?php


namespace Sansha\Quickbooks\Controller\Api;

use Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements CsrfAwareActionInterface
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $_map = array();

    protected $_hooks = array();

    protected $_errmap = array();

    protected $_helper_config;

    protected $_helper_data;

    protected $_helper_api;

    protected $_logger;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Sansha\Quickbooks\Helper\QbConfig $helperConfig,
        \Sansha\Quickbooks\Helper\QbData $helperData,
        \Sansha\Quickbooks\Helper\QbApi $helperApi,
        \Sansha\Quickbooks\Logger\Logger $logger
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_helper_config = $helperConfig;
        $this->_helper_data = $helperData;
        $this->_helper_api = $helperApi;
        $this->_logger = $logger;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
        {
            date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
        }

        $store_id = $this->_helper_data->getStoreId();
        $dsn = $this->_helper_config->getDsn($store_id);
        $qb_username = $this->_helper_config->getQbLogin($store_id)['username'];
        $qb_password = $this->_helper_config->getQbLogin($store_id)['password'];

        if(!\QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn)) {
            \QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);
            \QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $qb_username, $qb_password);
        }

        $server = new \QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $this->_map, $this->_errmap, $this->_hooks);
        $response = $server->handle(true, true); 
        die(); // stop code exectuon after server initialization
    }

    // below 2 functions will avoid breaking HTTP POST request
    public function createCsrfValidationException(RequestInterface $request): ?InvalidRequestException
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function validateForCsrf(RequestInterface $request): ?bool
    {
        return true;
    }
```